# Center columns for the exact size(ex. tablet) in Bulma

Tags: css, sass, bulma

How can one center the content of the column for the tablet(and larger screens) and have the content aligned to the right for the mobile using Bulma?

Comment: It's much easier to help, if you can put in the actual code. However IMHO, this might help you [Types responsive alignment](https://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/typography-helpers/#responsive-alignment)

Comment: Yes, lately I just used `text-align: center` and found the correct class for that. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align things in the column such like text or images in Bulma there are classes like `has-text-centered`, `has-text-left`, etc. .
These classes are described in [helper.sass](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/base/helpers.sass).